# Difference between the Mark of the Beast and the Seal of the Servants?

Tags: revelation, prophecy, ezekiel, symbolism, numerology

<sup>**Closely Related:**

- [Is the Mark of the Beast Actually Voluntary?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/29219/is-the-mark-of-the-beast-actually-voluntary)</sup>

***Is there a difference between the `"Mark of the Beast"`, and the `"Seal of the Servants"`?***  If so, what is the difference - how can people know which they have, (or getting)?

1. Could someone inadvertently get "the Mark of the Beast", thinking it was the "Seal of the Servants"?

   <sub>***Note:** I have also heard the "Seal of the Servants" called the "Mark of the Lamb".*</sub>
2. Or, Could someone mistakenly avoid the "Seal of the Servants", thinking it was the Mark of the Beast"?

**Issue:**  What is to say that the two "marks" are actually the same thing - but that the Book of Revelation might just be disinformation, *(from a Jewish point of view)*.

Or, is this a non-issue: [Is the Mark of the Beast Actually Voluntary?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/29219/is-the-mark-of-the-beast-actually-voluntary)

**The Seal of the Servants:**

> **NKJV, Ezekiel 9:4** - and the Lord said to him, “Go through the midst of the city, through the midst of Jerusalem, and put a mark on the foreheads of the men who sigh and cry over all the abominations that are done within it.”
>
> **NKJV, Ezekiel 9:6** - Utterly slay old and young men, maidens and little children and women; but do not come near anyone on whom is the mark; and begin at My sanctuary.” So they began with the elders who were before the temple.
>
> **NKJV, Revelation 7:3** - saying, “Do not harm the earth, the sea, or the trees till we have sealed the servants of our God on their foreheads.”

**The Mark of the Beast:**

> **NKJV, Revelation 13:17** - and that no one may buy or sell except one who has the mark or the name of the beast, or the number of his name.
>
> <sub>**Note:** There is a number of the name, a name, and a mark.  The "mark" appears different than "the name" or "number".</sub>

It strikes me kind of odd that there is so much analysis on the `"Mark of the Beast"`, when it seems that the "Mark of the Lamb" might be much, much, more important.

Comment: Related: http://dailydoseofgreek.com/scripture-passage/revelation-13-16/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two marks:

- the mark or seal of God
- the mark of the beast

A mark represents ownership. They that worshiped the beast received his mark (Revelation 13:8,12 - 18). In Revelation 7:2 we read of an angel descending from heaven having the seal of the living God and in 7:3 we read of the sealing of the servants of the living , the Jews God on their foreheads.

> Ephesians 1:13
>   13 In whom ye also trusted, after that ye heard the word of truth, the gospel of your salvation: in whom also after that ye believed, ye were sealed with that holy Spirit of promise.

The seal of God is the Holy Spirit, it is a mark of approval, a mark of ownership, it represents a finished work, a finished product and you are marked to your final destination. The mark of God is also a mark of liberty, liberty from sin after one hears the emancipation proclamation and believes he receives a mark, as a seal of circumcision, a mark of approval but those that believe not receive a mark of condemnation

> Romans 8:1-3:
>   1 There is therefore now no condemnation to them which are in Christ Jesus, who walk not after the flesh, but after the Spirit.
>   2 For the law of the Spirit of life in Christ Jesus hath made me free from the law of sin and death.
>   3 For what the law could not do, in that it was weak through the flesh, God sending his own Son in the likeness of sinful flesh, and for sin, condemned sin in the flesh:

The law had types and shadows of it.

> Deuteronomy 15:12-17
>   12 And if thy brother, an Hebrew man, or an Hebrew woman, be sold unto thee, and serve thee six years; then in the seventh year thou shalt let him go free from thee.
>   13 And when thou sendest him out free from thee, thou shalt not let him go away empty:
>   14 Thou shalt furnish him liberally out of thy flock, and out of thy floor, and out of thy winepress: of that wherewith the LORD thy God hath blessed thee thou shalt give unto him.
>   15 And thou shalt remember that thou wast a bondman in the land of Egypt, and the LORD thy God redeemed thee: therefore I command thee this thing to day.
>   16 And it shall be, if he say unto thee, I will not go away from thee; because he loveth thee and thine house, because he is well with thee;
>   17 Then thou shalt take an awl, and thrust it through his ear unto the door, and he shall be thy servant for ever. And also unto thy maidservant thou shalt do likewise.

Those, on hearing the emancipation proclamation, rejected their liberty were also marked, meaning they would forever be under servitude to their master.

In Ezekiel 8 the Angel with the writers ink horn went throughout Jerusalem marking the righteous to separate them from the wicked. Those that did not have the mark of approval were destroyed.

Comment: elikah kohen. I wish you ask this as a separate question but just to answer: the law was a shadow of new testament (Hebrews10: 1) and the shadow is incomplete without the image. The seal of God in the law was typed in the seal of circumcision Romans 4:11

11 And he received the sign of circumcision, a seal of the righteousness of the faith which he had yet being uncircumcised: that he might be the father of all them that believe, though they be not circumcised; that righteousness might be imputed unto them also: but the seal was completed in Christ in Colosians 2:11- 14  to fulfil Deut 30:6

Answer (score 2):

I've never heard the term "mark of the lamb", but I do understand your interpretation. But first, the term "mark of the beast" is generally understood by most serious students of the Bible. Found in Revelation 13:16, it is a mark some people will accept during the Tribulation Period which reflects their allegiance to the Antichrist. With this mark, they can buy, sell, and receive services needed during this terrible time. You should understand that times will be very difficult since resources will be limited, particularly when consider the effects of the seals, trumpets and bowls. The greater problem associated with the mark of the beast is anyone who takes the mark cannot be saved (Revelation 15:9-10). So the issue is starve, not receive medical care, etc., or take the mark. Many will rather suffer than to take the mark, knowing that taking the mark will ensure their eternal damnation. This is yet another reason to accept Christ today and avoid all of that. The rapture of the Church ensures Christians will not be here to go through this time of punishment (a pre-millennial position).

The incident in Ezekiel 9 is a vision by which Ezekiel sees God's judgment on unfaithful Israel ... at least those in Jerusalem aka the Southern Kingdom. The Northern Kingdom had already been taken away captive by the Assyrians because of their rebellion against the Lord in 2 Kings 18:912). Ezekiel 8 (the start of the vision) shows the many abominations, conducted in the Temple by the priest, elders and women, which polluted the Temple. This vision is God's way of telling Ezekiel who will die by the sword during Nebuchadnezzar's invasion of Jerusalem (the unrighteous), and who will live or survive the invasion (the righteous). Many others would die by famine (first mentioned in Ezekiel 5). The marking of those in Ezekiel 9 is not unlike God sparing Noah and his family before the flood (Noah was deemed righteous) or like the rapture before the Tribulation Period (the righteous in Christ will be taken away and thus not experience God's wrath). Hence, only the unsaved will enter the Tribulation Period). Actually, during the Tribulation Period, God tells the saints (those who become saved during this time) to remove themselves from Babylon before it is judged (Revelation 18:4). I believe this demonstrates God intention to never punish the righteous with the wicked, a concept first introduced by Abraham's questions to God concerning the destruction of Sodom in Genesis 18:20-33. In this passage, Abraham asked the question specifically ... "wilt thou also destroy the righteous with the wicked". The answer was no, and even Lot was told to leave Sodom before it was destroyed (Genesis 19:12-13). So, "the mark of the lamb", as you put it, is really a mark of protection against destruction.

Answer (score 0):

## Updated Answer

It is the nature of symbols that they lack sufficient specificity to confine them to one context so I'm not attempting to define the marks as to exclude any other application.

But at the heart of the idea of a "mark" is the mark that God put on Cain:

> [Gen 4:15 NLT] (15) The LORD replied, "No, for I will give a sevenfold punishment to anyone who kills you." Then the LORD put a mark on Cain to warn anyone who might try to kill him.

Please note that the mark did not provide protection, only vengeance.

I think that the point of the mark is to show who will be the avenger of the blood of the marked person and the extent to which they will be avenged (IE: 7 times, 70 times 7, etc.).

Since Cain, the murderer was to be avenged by God seven fold, how much more his innocent son? So it is yet another testimony to the imminent wrath being well deserved by all who reject the messiah.

This would then be somewhat encouraging in the face of martyrdom. No, the mark will not spare them from being killed for Christ but they will be violently avenged, restoring their honor:

> [Rev 6:9-11 NLT] (9) When the Lamb broke the fifth seal, I saw under the altar the souls of all who had been martyred for the word of God and for being faithful in their testimony. (10) They shouted to the Lord and said, "O Sovereign Lord, holy and true, how long before you judge the people who belong to this world and avenge our blood for what they have done to us?" (11) Then a white robe was given to each of them. And they were told to rest a little longer until the full number of their brothers and sisters--their fellow servants of Jesus who were to be martyred--had joined them.

## Original Answer

I [answered a similar question](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/35802/how-does-the-right-hand-and-forehead-for-the-mark-of-the-beast-correlate-to-the/40560?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C59.3976#40560) and I believe my commentary is equally or even more relevant to this question. Paul seems to suggest that a major element of the "crime" involved in being a Christian is the vote of no confidence that a Christian makes in regard to the Sinai covenant. The law is rejected by Christians as being a factor in justification and that stance is the basis for persecution:

> [Gal 5:11 KJV] (11) And I, brethren, if I yet preach circumcision, why do I yet suffer persecution? then is the offence of the cross ceased.

## Update #2!

I wrote an extended [superior version](https://www.quora.com/q/hrkefqdtjmfzfcrs/Can-you-guys-help-me-Do-any-of-you-know-where-Jesus-or-an-Apostle-mentions-the-Mark-of-the-Beast-outside-of-Revelation-16) of my original explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The mark of the beast has to do with worship, but not the worship you see today in the churches, temples, synagogues, mosques, etc. The worship is called submission under an authority. In simple terms, it's whose instructions you follow or who is your master or leader.

Believe it or not, humans cannot have their own identities outside of God. I know this is the quest of Science but it's not possible. Life comes from God and there is no life outside of him. His spirit gives life. This mere fact leaves two options:

1. Follow God
2. Go against God

Following God, the scriptures liken to "entering the kingdom of heaven" and "receiving his seal". Not following God is likened to "worshipping the beast" and "receiving the mark".

Two kingdoms. Two Marks. One Choice.

Most people choose option 2 because it's easier: you don't get persecuted and you get an easy life with lots of toys and gadgets. Plus you get a job, friends, no shunning from religion and the anti-religious, no ridicule about your fake God and so on. Option 1 is better but tough.

A more in-depth explanation can be found on this topic on this website or in this book. Both hold the same premise that scriptures must be used to explain scriptures rather than speculation or fanciful incantations based on secular wild ideas.

1. [The mark of the beast: dispelling the lies and escaping the mark - Kindle, Paperback, Hardback](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B09SDKGQ8V/ref=as_li_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=1634&creative=6738&creativeASIN=B09SDKGQ8V&linkCode=as2&tag=tog07-21&linkId=3a37592ef38bfeb2dd96ae8f65186cf2)
2. [The mark of the beast series - Main Points](https://www.wakeuplookandsee.com/series/the-mark-of-the-beast-series/)

Answer (score 0):

Everyone on here stating things that all point to the same truth but no one  fully got there.
I’ve read it’s about being righteous or not, keeping the law or not, circumcised or not.
For me, its simple, Gods seal is in the law!

Fourth commandment contains his seal (name:God, title:The Lord, kingdom: heaven earth seas and all that is in them)! Keeping the sabbath determines where you are keeping the law and receiving the seal of God, or you are not and instead receiving the mark of the beast.

The beast is identified in prophecy and looking back at history whilst comparing to revelations we see that the Catholic Church is clearly the beast.
Who removed the 4th commandments from practice?
Who changed worship to Sunday?
Didn’t all the Protestant churches come out of the Catholic Church and still pay homage to it by keeping Sunday worship? Is that not a command of man?

Also looking in Genesis we see Gods blessings on creation, his first blessing was in the life created of plants, insects, and birds! His second blessing was on life he created in beasts, and man and woman! His third blessing was on his sabbath day of rest!
The fourth commandment is the seal of God, and was blessed and sanctified by God! Which means he made it Holy and set it apart for sacred keeping. He then gave his commands to his people and placed his seal upon that command only! That God’s people will “remember the sabbath day, to keep it holy”!
If you are a Sunday worshipper you are not worshiping the God of creation, or the Son who kept the commandments and told his disciples “if you love me, keep my commandments”, and who also rested on Sabbath, preached on sabbath. He even rested on sabbath in death and rose on Sunday to get back to work!

So if your worshiping Jesus on Sunday your worshiping the false prophet, your not keeping the commandment of God that he blessed, sanctified and sealed, then you will relieve the mark of the beast. The mark of the beast will be a Sunday law, that people will be forced to worship on Sunday and you are expected by God to stand firm in his word to keep his seal and resist being persecuted for following his law.

That’s what I believe the mark to be.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center's](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help) sections on both asking and answering questions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

We can gain more understanding about the mark of the beast by looking at scripture.

> They cried out, “Away with him, away with him, crucify him!” Pilate said to them, “Shall I crucify your King?” The chief priests answered, “We have no king but Caesar.”
>   -- John 19:15 (ESV)

I think Pilate could have said here "I give you your husband" and it would have been accurate. Instead they choose Barabbas, a murder and a troubler of the city, which is a prophetic type and shadow of who they really are choosing and who's mark and name they take in the earth. The number or a name of man which is incomplete at its best.

So who is this or who are they, they that make their stand in the earth under the banner or the name of their husband, their ruler or their God?

> <sup>1</sup>Why do the nations conspire
>   and the peoples plot in vain?
>   <sup>2</sup>The kings of the earth rise up
>   and the rulers band together
>   against the Lord and against his anointed, saying
>   <sup>3</sup> Let us break their chains
>   and throw off their shackles
>   -- Psalm 2:1-3 (NIV)

Scripture interprets itself and in this case it's Peter that has the understanding:

> <sup>23</sup>When they were released, they went to their friends and reported what the chief priests and the elders had said to them...
>   <sup>25</sup>who through the mouth of our father David, your servant, said by the Holy Spirit
>   *Why did the Gentiles rage,
>
>   and the peoples plot in vain?
>
>   <sup>26</sup>The kings of the earth set themselves,
>
>   and the rulers were gathered together,
>
>   against the Lord and against his Anointed*
>   <sup>27</sup>for truly in this city there were gathered together against your holy servant Jesus, whom you anointed, both Herod and Pontius Pilate, along with the Gentiles and the peoples of Israel
>   -- Acts 4:23,25-27 (ESV)

Answer (score -1):

This dichotomy is easily solved by the reasoning of those who were saved and those who were not.  God does everything by number, weight and measure.  The Law forbid images of things in heaven, earth and sea and their worship.  All the images in Jerusalem were unlawful idols of wood and stone: stone temple, wooden altar, stone tablets (Moses hewed the stones), wooden ark, etc.  The Israelites (man's number is 6) built the temple in the image of man (6) and man brought man's wages into it. (666).  This is symbolized by the 'cube' of the Holy of Holies in the earthly kingdom versus the New Jerusalem's cube made up of people. 1x1x1=1.  A 'cube' has 3 dimensions.  This 'cube' was also a magic number cube used by pagan priests and the numbers totaled 666.  They wore these amulets as good luck charms.  The Israelites forgot god (which the temple symbolized) and began to worship the 'creation more than the creator.'  They refused their Messiah and his spiritual kingdom, believing that their Savior would be of royality and would rule on the throne in earthly Jerusalem and make all other nations bow down to them.  They had the law written on their foreheads (the High Priest had god's name written there) and on their hands.  This Queen which sat at the right hand of her King as a mediator between two alienated parties until reconciliation came was about to go into the Abyss.  She was no longer a faithful wife (Queen status) but had become the wanton harlot and her kingdom had become 'Babylon.'  She had killed her prophets, Messiah and the saints and blood for blood was required by law under the old covenant.  Her synagogues in every city of the Roman Empire were synagogues of Satan, the 'Adversary.'  They were 'adversaries' of Christ and his kingdom.  Is 66:6.  When ShE was 'cast out' so was the ADVERSARY confined to the ABYSS. Jesus referred to Peter as 'Satan' meaning he was adversarial to the mission of Christ. The bible is about covenant eschatology and is a complete, concise account of creation, god's eternal covenant seed, man's dying in his relationship with his father and the restoration of mankind at the end of the old covenant kingdom.  During the intermission God used 3rd parties as mediators between the two, such as the Priest of Salem, and the Aaronic priesthood and prophets until all things were restored.  The dichotomy of flesh vs spirit, seen vs unseen, temporal vs eternal, external vs internal will clearly identify who had the mark of the Beast.  Beasts were part of the curses of the old national covenant, therefore it was finished by the end of that age.  Heb 8:13; 1 Pet 4:7.

Comment: Hi Anna. Please break up that big paragraph into smaller ones. It is impossible to read such a dense paragraph. In fact, your answers will be better received if you just make one or two main points instead of lots of little points. There are formatting tools also that make it more readable. Thanks.